# What's other possible ways to justify that?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be an n×m matrix and let D be a matrix such that AD=I*n* (where I*n* is the n×n identity matrix). Show that the equation Ax = b has a solution for every b ∈ Rn.

I tried to assume the matrix A is invertible, but it's wrong because it may not even be square.

Comment: Hint. Note that $ADb=I_nb$.

Comment: "*I tried to assume the matrix $A$ is invertible, but it's wrong because it may not even be square*"  Good.  You stopped yourself from making a major mistake.  It is never correct to assume a matrix is invertible, ever, unless you have direct evidence to suggest otherwise.  Assuming it is invertible can cause incorrect or circular results.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: This is a special case of a much more general fact: if a function has a right inverse, then it is [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Surjections_as_right_invertible_functions). In your case, $A$ is (or induces) a function from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$. Since $AD = I$, $A$ has a right inverse (namely $D$), hence $A$ is surjective, hence its image is all of $R^n$, hence every vector in $R^n$ can be expressed as $Ax$ for some $x \in \mathbb R^m$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C(A)$ denote column space of $A$ and $R(A)$ denote row space of $A$. We know that $C(AB) \subset C(A)$ and $R(AB) \subset R(B)$. By using this fact we know $C(A) \supset C(I_n)=\mathbb{R}^n$, so thus $C(A)=\mathbb{R}^n$. This means that the set of all linear combination of the columns of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence for any $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $x_1,...,x_m$ such that $x_1v_1+...+x_mv_m=b$ where $v_i$ is $i^{th}$ column vector of $A$. If we choose $x=(x_1,...,x_m)^T$, we have $Ax=b$